# Visual Studio 2017 won't start my WebApp (in Google Chrome) anymore after starting a couple of times

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, iis

So I'm working on modifying some code to allow for French translations to be added, works fine, code is going well. It's an MVC application by the way. I can start the app using VS to run it in Google Chrome just fine for a few runs, then all of a sudden it just won't start anymore. Everything builds, no errors, a new Google Chrome tab opens but it keeps saying "Loading..." and it's apparently trying to connect to my localhost but can't seem to find it or properly start?

When I restart my PC it's fine, but now It's the second time restarting my application and it doesn't work anymore again... I can restart my PC every time but that's just tedious and time consuming...

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Could it be something with IIS (as I assume that hosts the webapp when I'm running it locally from VS)?